# Different P-values between wilcox_test() & wilcox.test() in R

Tags: r, statistical-test, rstatix

While I was trying to perform a paired Wilcoxon test for the variable "Metabolite", I noticed different p-values between `wilcox_test()` & `wilcox.test()` when I tested the following variable:

```
structure(list(Visit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("BSL", "LV"), class = "factor"), Metabolite = c(NA, 
9.602, 9.0102, 4.524, 3.75, NA, 6.596, 7.065, 6.877, NA, NA, 
10.1846, 13.521, 7.8219, NA, 4.9149, 4.0754, 4.7635, 8.8554, 
4.3442, NA, 16.659, NA, 3.698, 6.623, 5.158, 11.719, 3.206, NA, 
2.225, 7.417, 1.42, NA, NA, 2.752, 6.504, 7.594, 6.652, NA, NA, 
3.784, 2.7311, 4.1749, 2.6659, 0.5592, NA, 4.2326, 4.3808, 3.624, 
4.29, 7.098, 6.532, 3.699, 9.297, 8.275, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L))



# The p-value derived from result 1 (p=0.0079) is different from that from result 2 (p=0.003279):


        result1 <- wilcox_test(data=Data_pairs,  Metabolite~Visit, paired = TRUE)
        
        # A tibble: 1 x 7
        #.y.     group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
        #* <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
        #        1 Metabolite BSL    LV        28    28       131 0.0079
        
        
        result2 <- wilcox.test(data=Data_pairs,  Metabolite~Visit, paired = TRUE)
        #   Wilcoxon signed rank exact test
        
        #data:  Metabolite by Visit
        #V = 197, p-value = 0.003279
        #alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Using different statistical software, it seems that the wrong p-value is that derived from `result2`.

Is there any suggestion/advice on how to correct my code and what is the reason for this difference?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 1) your `result1` is not reproducible; 2) `coin::wilcox_test` is not a paired test and does not have a `paired` argument; 3) see note in `?wilcox.test`: `The formula interface is only applicable for the 2-sample tests.`

Comment: wilcox_test is from rstatix, not coin, think OP should clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

You should point out you are using rstatix to avoid the confusion:

```
rstatix::wilcox_test(data=Data_pairs,  Metabolite~Visit, paired = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  .y.        group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
* <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Metabolite BSL    LV        28    28       131 0.0079
```

If it is indeed paired data, then you need to ensure you provide the complete pairs, taking your data, we can place them side by side, assuming the your observations 1 to 28 and from the same sample as 29 to 56:

```
da = do.call(cbind,split(Data_pairs$Metabolite,Data_pairs$Visit))
da

          BSL     LV
 [1,]      NA     NA
 [2,]  9.6020 2.2250
 [3,]  9.0102 7.4170
 [4,]  4.5240 1.4200
 [5,]  3.7500     NA
 [6,]      NA     NA
 [7,]  6.5960 2.7520
 [8,]  7.0650 6.5040
 [9,]  6.8770 7.5940
[10,]      NA 6.6520
[11,]      NA     NA
[12,] 10.1846     NA
[13,] 13.5210 3.7840
[14,]  7.8219 2.7311
[15,]      NA 4.1749
[16,]  4.9149 2.6659
[17,]  4.0754 0.5592
[18,]  4.7635     NA
[19,]  8.8554 4.2326
[20,]  4.3442 4.3808
[21,]      NA 3.6240
[22,] 16.6590 4.2900
[23,]      NA 7.0980
[24,]  3.6980 6.5320
[25,]  6.6230 3.6990
[26,]  5.1580 9.2970
[27,] 11.7190 8.2750
[28,]  3.2060     NA
```

We test only the complete:

```
wilcox.test(da[complete.cases(da),1],da[complete.cases(da),2],paired=TRUE)

data:  da[complete.cases(da), 1] and da[complete.cases(da), 2]
V = 131, p-value = 0.007904
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: I am sorry for not pointing out that the package was: rstatix. Yes, my observations 1 to 28 are paired with the 29 to 56.
I have a dataset of >10.000 metabolites, and therefore my dataset is in a long format; thus, I wondered if the wilcox.test() applies to this type of data structure. Thank you all very much for your help.